# Modificando a memória de um processo com C++ WinApi

Tags: c++, memória, winapi

Eu estou tentando fazer um programinha para minha universidade no qual consegue alterar valores da memória de outro processo. Com o endereço exato da variável que o Cheat Engine me dá é bem tranquilo mas caso eu feche o programa alvo e abra-o novamente os endereços não serão os mesmos, então o meu problema são os ponteiros de memória. Na imagem à seguir eu fiz um pointer scan map para verificar aonde eu posso achar os seguintes ponteiros que me levam ao valor:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu já fiz um protótipo mas ele não funciona muito bem, toda hora me retorna um código de erro 299 que significa: "Only part of a ReadProcessMemory or WriteProcessMemory request was completed." coisa que com o endereço bruto que o CE me dá apenas de achar o valor da variável não acontece. O código que fiz está ai:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <Psapi.h>
#include <TlHelp32.h>
#include <queue>

using namespace std;

   int main() {
   PROCESSENTRY32 pEntry;
   pEntry.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);

   // Snapshot to list all process
   HANDLE pHandlers = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS,0);
   if (pHandlers == NULL) {
       cout << "Error 1";
       return 1;
   }
   // Listing process
   if (Process32First(pHandlers, &pEntry)) {
       while (Process32Next(pHandlers, &pEntry)) {

           // Convert value to string
           wstring wstr(pEntry.szExeFile);
           string str(wstr.begin(), wstr.end());
           // Check if is the process that i wan't
           if (str == "Playgroundd.exe") {
               MODULEENTRY32 mEntry;
               mEntry.dwSize = sizeof(MODULEENTRY32);
            
               // Snapshot to list all modules inside process
               HANDLE mHandlers = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPMODULE, pEntry.th32ProcessID);
               if (mHandlers == NULL) {
                   cout << "Error 2";
                   return 1;
               }
            
               // Usually the first process is the main module
               if (Module32First(mHandlers, &mEntry)) {

                   // Convert the name to string
                   wstring wstrr(mEntry.szExePath);
                   string strr(wstrr.begin(), wstrr.end());
                   if (strr.find("Playgroundd.exe")) {

                       // Get the base address of module
                       DWORD moduleBaseAddress = (DWORD)mEntry.modBaseAddr;

                       // Append initial value
                       moduleBaseAddress += (DWORD)0x000000E8;

                       // Offsets defined
                       DWORD offsets[] = {0x88,0x98,0x90,0x20,0x10,0x48,0x904};

                       // Open process with the right process id
                       cout << "process id: " << pEntry.th32ProcessID << endl << endl;
                       HANDLE processHandler = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, 0, pEntry.th32ProcessID);
                       if (processHandler == NULL) {
                           cout << "Can't open the process";
                           return 1;
                       }
                       // Sum offsets 
                       for (int i = 0; i < 7;i++) {
                           moduleBaseAddress += offsets[i];
                       }

                       int receive = 0;
                       size_t bytesRead = 0;

                       bool resultStatus = ReadProcessMemory(processHandler, 
   (LPCVOID)moduleBaseAddress, &receive, sizeof(receive), &bytesRead);
                       cout << "result status :" << resultStatus << endl;
                       cout << "Received : " << receive << endl;
                       cout << "Bytes read : " << bytesRead << endl;
                       cout <<  "Possible error code : " <<  GetLastError() << endl;
                    
                   }
                   else {
                       cout << "Can't find module";
                       return 1;
                   }
               }
           }
       }
   }
};
```

Essa é a saída do programa rodando em modo administador,pode-se ignorar o "possible error code" caso "result status" for diferente de 0:

```
result status :0
Received : 0
Bytes read : 0
Possible error code : 299
```

Oque eu estaria fazendo de errado?